# Pandas python relative questions instead of sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a question on how I can implement this type of functionality in pandas.
I have the following fields

[image]

and I would like to ask the following question. Find those ueid (last column) that tend to travel the largest distances (dist column).

I have tried to solve this with ordering but then if I order for ueid first and then second for distance I will not get what I want.

Then if I order for distance it will not be easy to see which are the ueid that come more often up in the list.

Can you advice of how pandas can support me here?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: [please do not post code and/or dataframes as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: that is a useful comment. How I can take some rows of a data frame and convert it to executable code?

Comment: Copy your dataframe, paste it in the question editor, to edit go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56984444/edit), and highlight it, then hit Ctrl + K then hit Save Edits then you're done

Comment: but that would be hardly usable to anyone here they can not use it for executing something or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first `uied` with the largest `dist`:

```
df.loc[df['dist'].idxmax(),'uied']
```

Get all `uied`'s with the largest `dist`:

```
df.loc[df['dist']==df['dist'].max(),'uied']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your expectation is not really clear for a query.

If I understand right, I think you want to know which people often go for long-distance travel. This is my solution:

- Find top n longest-distance
- Find uid who has m% travel in this top n.

n and m is your choice.

Comment: exactly .. that is what I want and if I am not wrong this is not possible with normal panda queries

Comment: you can do the above step after choosing m,n. You can start by analyze all distances to know how much is "long-distance" in your mind.
If you think this is the answer, please upvote and tick it as accepted answer